# The native map in ionic 3 doesn't work

Tags: google-maps, ionic3, native

I followed this repo to create the google map native in Ionic
[ionic google maps demo](https://github.com/mapsplugin/ionic-googlemaps-quickdemo)
I can not debug to see what's happened, only white screen.
I used **native/core: 4.7.0** and **@ionic-native/google-maps: ^4.7.0** and **cordova-plugin-googlemaps: 2.2.9**.
I enabled google map API already, and get the right key

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing it on the browser? `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` is a native plug-in and cannot be view on browser. For testing, you will need to build it and test it on your device.

Read more here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/testing.html